# Pandas - sorting x columns by top x highest last values from all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
           date    World  Afghanistan  Albania  Algeria  Andorra  ...  Vatican  Venezuela  Vietnam  Yemen  Zambia  Zimbabwe
0    2019-12-31       27          0.0      NaN      0.0      NaN  ...      NaN        NaN      0.0    NaN     NaN       NaN
1    2020-01-01       27          0.0      NaN      0.0      NaN  ...      NaN        NaN      0.0    NaN     NaN       NaN
2    2020-01-02       27          0.0      NaN      0.0      NaN  ...      NaN        NaN      0.0    NaN     NaN       NaN
3    2020-01-03       44          0.0      NaN      0.0      NaN  ...      NaN        NaN      0.0    NaN     NaN       NaN
4    2020-01-04       44          0.0      NaN      0.0      NaN  ...      NaN        NaN      0.0    NaN     NaN       NaN
..          ...      ...          ...      ...      ...      ...  ...      ...        ...      ...    ...     ...       ...
102  2020-04-11  1653206        521.0    416.0   1761.0    601.0  ...      8.0      175.0    257.0    1.0    40.0      11.0
103  2020-04-12  1734913        555.0    433.0   1825.0    622.0  ...      8.0      175.0    258.0    1.0    40.0      14.0
104  2020-04-13  1807303        607.0    446.0   1914.0    638.0  ...      8.0      181.0    262.0    1.0    43.0      14.0
105  2020-04-14  1873265        665.0    467.0   1983.0    646.0  ...      8.0      189.0    265.0    1.0    45.0      17.0
106  2020-04-15  1948511        714.0    475.0   2070.0    659.0  ...      8.0      193.0    274.0    1.0    45.0      17.0
```

I know I can get last values from each column, like so:

```
countries = list(df)[2:]
for item in df:
  value = df[item].iloc[-1]
```

But what I actually need is all column values for countries which have the top 10 highest last values. How can I sort that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select last row with all columns withiut first 2 by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), get 10 top values by [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), get index values and filter columns names:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv')
top10 = df.iloc[-1, 2:].astype(float).nlargest(10)
print (top10)
United States     609516.0
Spain             172541.0
Italy             162488.0
Germany           127584.0
France            103573.0
United Kingdom     93873.0
China              83352.0
Iran               74877.0
Turkey             65111.0
Belgium            31119.0
Name: 106, dtype: float64
```

---

```
top10 = df[df.iloc[-1, 2:].astype(float).nlargest(10).index]
print (top10)
     United States   Spain   Italy  Germany  France  United Kingdom  China  \
0                0       0       0        0       0               0     27   
1                0       0       0        0       0               0     27   
2                0       0       0        0       0               0     27   
3                0       0       0        0       0               0     44   
4                0       0       0        0       0               0     44   
..             ...     ...     ...      ...     ...             ...    ...   
102         501560  157022  147577   117658   90676           70272  83004   
103         529951  161852  152271   120479   93790           78991  83097   
104         557571  166019  156363   123016   95403           84279  83209   
105         582594  169496  159516   125098   98076           88621  83303   
106         609516  172541  162488   127584  103573           93873  83352   

      Iran   Turkey  Belgium  
0        0      NaN        0  
1        0      NaN        0  
2        0      NaN        0  
3        0      NaN        0  
4        0      NaN        0  
..     ...      ...      ...  
102  68192  47029.0    26667  
103  70029  52167.0    28018  
104  71686  56956.0    29647  
105  73303  61049.0    30589  
106  74877  65111.0    31119  

[107 rows x 10 columns]
```

For `DatetimeIndex` convert first column of data to index and datetimes in `read_csv`:

```
url = 'https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
top10 = df[df.iloc[-1, 1:].astype(float).nlargest(10).index]
print (top10)
            United States   Spain   Italy  Germany  France  United Kingdom  \
date                                                                         
2019-12-31              0       0       0        0       0               0   
2020-01-01              0       0       0        0       0               0   
2020-01-02              0       0       0        0       0               0   
2020-01-03              0       0       0        0       0               0   
2020-01-04              0       0       0        0       0               0   
                  ...     ...     ...      ...     ...             ...   
2020-04-11         501560  157022  147577   117658   90676           70272   
2020-04-12         529951  161852  152271   120479   93790           78991   
2020-04-13         557571  166019  156363   123016   95403           84279   
2020-04-14         582594  169496  159516   125098   98076           88621   
2020-04-15         609516  172541  162488   127584  103573           93873   

            China   Iran   Turkey  Belgium  
date                                        
2019-12-31     27      0      NaN        0  
2020-01-01     27      0      NaN        0  
2020-01-02     27      0      NaN        0  
2020-01-03     44      0      NaN        0  
2020-01-04     44      0      NaN        0  
          ...    ...      ...      ...  
2020-04-11  83004  68192  47029.0    26667  
2020-04-12  83097  70029  52167.0    28018  
2020-04-13  83209  71686  56956.0    29647  
2020-04-14  83303  73303  61049.0    30589  
2020-04-15  83352  74877  65111.0    31119  

[107 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: I need all values as well, for each of theses top_10...must plot the progression. sorry if I was not clear

Comment: I need to extract all column values from `nlargest(x)`

Comment: @8-BitBorges - Can you test now?

Comment: yes. something is not right. US, France, Italy and other 7 most infected countries should be filtered. last value from each column is the last entry os number of cases. But low cases are being filtered

Comment: this is the `df = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv')`

Comment: in case you need the data.

Comment: it sorts the right countries. but does no fetch all rows from each of them. basically I need a new df with those countries, with all rows, showing the progression of cases , ie the timeline for those 10.

Comment: yeah. you're such a master.